# is it possible to detect uninstallation of current application?

Tags: android

DETECTING APPLICTION UNINSTALLATION

i want to invoke a method  when current running appliation is being uninstalling,
is it possible to detect uninstallation of current application ?

Comment: from where you want to detect it? From the application that is uninstalled?

Comment: yes i want to detect from  the application  that is being uninstalling .@VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: it is not possible then

Comment: It was possible long ago. It was abused and Google stopped that. Someone found another way. Google stopped that too. If you can refine the question maybe someone can suggest a way to achieve your actual goal.

Comment: @arnt  thank you for giving hope on this question , might be i need to wait for  some time to get to solve this issue.

Comment: probably if you tell us what exactly you wnat to do when uninstalling, we could suggest another way?

Comment: Maybe you can write a service that stores all the names of the installed apps in a database. And send a notification if some apps are no longer found on the system.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko  i want to pass value to  remote server while uninstalling

Comment: which value you want to pass?

Comment: just i want to invoke a method on uninstalling

Answer (score 1):

Yes it kind of achievable using FCM, send an fcm data notification to the device

*How to use FCM for finding uninstalled users?*

If the user uninstalls the app, the device token provided by FCM will become invalid over time. You can find it from the message error response codes https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#error-codes find HTTP code **200 + error:NotRegistered** if u got this error there is a high chance the app is uninstalled on that device